# Line integral over an ellipse

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have some troubles wit the next exercise.

> Find the required work for move a particle from the point $(1,0)$ to the point $(-1,0)$ trought the ellipse $x^2+\displaystyle\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ against to the force $F(x,y)=(3y^2+2,16x)$. Which value of $b$ minimizes the work?

First, consider $\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),-b\sin(t))$ the parametrization of the ellipse. The sign in the second coordinate is because the field goes counterclockwise, and, then, the parametrization should be goes clockwise.

Then, $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}(3b^2\sin^2(t)+2,16\cos(t))\cdot(-\sin(t),-b\cos(t))\,dt$$The integral then is $$\int_{0}^{\pi}-3b^2\sin^3(t)-2\sin(t)-16b\cos^2(t)\,dt$$And the value is $-4b^2-8b\pi-4$ but, this function of $b$ doesn't have minimum, only a maximum. What happened here? What is wrong with my exercise?

Comment: You wrote $. (-\sin $ instead of $. (\sin/$

Comment: Who said you must go on the lower half of the ellipse instead of on the upper one?

Comment: I did it because the ellipse goes against the field. Then, the parametrization of the ellipse should be clockwise because the field goes counterclockwise.

Comment: You choose whether you want the orientation to be clockwise or counterclockwise, not the vector field. I think the biggest confusion is, just because you are not heading in the direction in which the vector field is rotating, doesn't mean you don't have to exert energy, your travel just isn't affected as much.

Comment: Ok. If I take a parametrization $(\cos(t),b\sin(t))$, then, the function of b doesn't have minimum.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez The final result is a quadratic in $\;b\;$ with *negative coefficient* (and it does **not** matter whether you change the sign of the second coordinate in the curve's parametrization: the quadratic ceofficient's sign remains), and thus it can't have a minimal value...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Just to be clear, in this case it does not matter, but in general it does.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood What does? A sign? Of course it matters in general!

Comment: @DonAntonio: The sign in the second coordinate was placed to give the clockwise orientation of the curve. I was just saying that when you said the sign doesn't matter, you mean in this case. In general, changing the sign of the second coordinate could change the orientation and thus change the work integral.

Comment: Finally, the work doesn't have minimum.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood **Of course** I meant in this case! This is what we're dealing with, right? That **always** change the orientation (in an ellipse...), but **in this case**, where the OP wanted a minimal value, that doens't matter: a minimal value still doesn't exist as we get a downwards parabola...

Comment: Yes. The minimum of the function. Then, how can I conclude the exercises?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez With an "either there's a mistake or a typo in the question, but..." and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I know you understand well what is going on. I was just point ing it out for the OP because I had commented saying orientation doesn't matter and then you post something that seems to go against that. I was just trying to be clear. No harm meant.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Also, I didn't do the problem before my post, that's why I only had text in my answer. I seen the sign change that the OP did, and the reasoning was off, so I figured he/she went wrong due to that. It wasn't until we all really looked at the problem and realized that the sign didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppose to have that negative in the second component. You are computing a work integral over the ellipse. Unless stated otherwise, it is always assumed that curves are given the counter clock-wise orientation. Note that orientation really does matter since the force field may be stronger (or weaker) in the opposing direction.

\begin{align*} &\int_{0}^\pi (3 \sin^2t + 2,16 \cos t) \cdot (- \sin t, b\cos t) \ dt \\ & = \int_{0}^\pi -3b^2 \sin^3t- 2 \sin t + 16 b\cos^2t \ dt \\ & = -4b^2+8 \pi b - 4 \end{align*}

Comment: Why does the sign of the second component even matter?  The problem is the coefficient $-4$ of $b^2$.  It's going to dominate in either case and give a parabola which opens down.

Comment: @sharding4 You should probably read my above comment on this post. In short, the vector field can be more aggressive or weaker depending on where you are, so going in a different direction can require less or more energy. Imagine traveling home with a high wind blowing at you, versus going in a different direction and never encountering much wind at all.

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization is, (of course, assuming $\;b>0$). As commented, it really doesn't matter whether we change the sign of the second coordiante *in this case*:

$$r(t)=(\cos t,\,b\sin t\;) , \;\;0\le t\le \pi\implies r'(t)=(-\sin t,\,b\cos t)$$

and then

$$F(r(t))=(3b^2\sin^2t+2,\,16\cos t)\implies F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)=-3b^2\sin^3t-2\sin t+16b\cos^2t$$

and thus the work is (observe that $\;\int\sin^3t\,dt=\int(\sin t-\sin t\cos^2t)dt=-\cos t+\frac13\cos^3t+C\;$

$$\int_0^\pi\left(-3b^2\sin^3t-2\sin t+16b\cos^2t\right)dt=$$

$$=\frac{3b^2}2\left(\cos t-\frac13\cos^3t\right)_0^\pi+2\cos t|_0^\pi+\left.8b(t+\cos t\sin t)\right|_0^\pi=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac{3b^2}2\left(-1+\frac13-1+\frac13\right)+2(-1-1)+8b(\pi)=$$

$$=-2b^2-4+8b\pi$$

This doesn't have a minimum but it does have a maximum at $\;b=2\pi\;$